# Limit behavior of "weighted" Poisson Binomial distribution

Tags: asymptotics, poisson-binomial-distribution

Given $X_n \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n, p_n)$ it is known by the Poisson Limit Theorem that as $n \to \infty$ that $$X_n \to \operatorname{Poisson}(np_n).$$

This can be generalized to hold for Poisson Binomial distributions where the binomial distributions base probability $p$ varies between trials. This is Le Cam's Theorem: Given $X_n \sim \operatorname{PoiBin}(\{p_1, \dots, p_n\})$, as $n \to \infty$ we have $$X_n \to \operatorname{Poisson}\left(\sum_1^n p_i\right).$$

Consider a "Weighted" Poisson Binomial distribution $$X_n \sim \sum_1^n w_i \operatorname{Bernoulli}(p_i).$$ Given suitable stability conditions on the weights $w_i$ is there a way to generalize Le Cam's theorem further to say that as $n \to \infty$ we have $$X_n \to \operatorname{Poisson}\left(\sum_1^n w_ip_i\right)?$$

Notes: When $n$ gets truly large and with suitable stability conditions all of these tend to normal distributions by a generalization of the central limit theorem. I'm just looking at if they approach a Poisson distribution on the way. Stability conditions would apply to both $\{w_i\}$ and $\{p_i\}$ either way. Also, all Bernoulli trials are independent, though not necessarily identically distributed.

Comment: Based on Probability Theory: the Coupling Method by Frank den Hollander available online, I suspect this holds so long as $\frac{\sum{w_i^2p_i^2}{\sum{w_ip_i}\to 0$.